# Generate PDF of a specific range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I've made a code that generate a PDF of the sheet, but as you can see, it needs to hide and the show the pages that i don't want to in the final result. Is there a way to generate a PDF only for a specific range wich i'll declare?

```
    function createPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss1 = ss.getSheetByName ("Monitor"); //Pega a aba do PDF
  var NomePDF = ss1.getRange("A1:A1").getValue(); //Pega o nome do PDF
  var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName ("PDF"); //Pega a aba do gatilho pro PDF
  var Confirmacao = ss2.getRange ("A1:A1") .getValue(); //Pega o gatilho pro PDF

  var FolderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("2023"); //Pega a pasta dentro do Drive
  var PdfFolder = FolderIter.next(); //Entra na pasta

  var Spreadsheet_id = ss.getId(); //Pega o ID da planilha atual
  var Spreadsheetfile = DriveApp.getFileById(Spreadsheet_id); //Pega a planilha dentro do Drive pelo ID
  var Blob = Spreadsheetfile.getAs(MimeType.PDF); //Pega a planilha dentro do Drive como PDF
  
  var ss2 = ss.getSheetByName ("PDF"); //Referenciando a aba PDF da planilha em uma variável 
  ss2.hideSheet(); //Função para esconder a variável
  
  PdfFolder.createFile(Blob).setName(NomePDF); //Salva a planilha como PDF dentro do Drive

  ss2.showSheet(); //Função para mostrar novamente a variável

}
```

Comment: About your question of `Is there a way to generate a PDF only for a specific range wich i'll declare?`, I thought that this thread might be an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62861704

Comment: It truly is, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad that leads to the answer. From your reply, I flagged it as a duplicate question.